# How to extend OpenOCD to support a not supported Targe?

Tags: embedded, openocd, jtag

I like to extend the OpenOCD software to support a target microcontroller (Target Layer) that is not yet supported. How I have to start with? Is there someone had already similar experience?

I have access to all microcontroller JTAG and OCDS details and documentation, so, I would just need an hint of what files to be generated and modified in the OpenOCD project.

At the end I would like to have another microcontroller liste in the "Target Layer" list of OpenOCD (https://sourceforge.net/projects/openocd/files/openocd/0.10.0/)